# Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at CRC_configurable.v(62) near text: "integer"; expecting "end"

Tags: for-loop, case, verilog

I'm working with Quartus Prime Lite Edition and having a `case` statement with:

```
S2: begin
            dat[WID_DAT-1 :1] <= dat[WID_DAT-2 :0];
            dat[0] <= 0;
            crc[0] <= crc_temp[0];
            integer i;
            for (i = 1; i < WID_CRC; i = i+1) begin
                crc[i] <= crc_temp[i] ^ crc[i-1];
            end
            
            if(count != 0) begin
                r_ns <= S2;
                count <= count -1;
            end
            
            else begin
            r_ns <= S_DONE;
            done <= 1;
            end
        end
```

and get the error message when I Start Anlysis & Elaboration:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at CRC_configurable.v(62) near
> text: "integer";  expecting "end".

Why is this so, and how should I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not declare an `integer` in the middle of a `begin/end` block.  You could move the `integer` declaration line outside of the `always` block (before it).

```
integer i;

always ... 
...
S2: begin
            dat[WID_DAT-1 :1] <= dat[WID_DAT-2 :0];
            dat[0] <= 0;
            crc[0] <= crc_temp[0];
            for (i = 1; i < WID_CRC; i = i+1) begin
                crc[i] <= crc_temp[i] ^ crc[i-1];
            end
```

Or, if you give your begin block a name, you should be able to declare the `integer` immediately after the `begin` line.